# DC 30v Adjustable PSU using Lm317

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, lm317

[This is the adapter i got in My hand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MsV9.jpg)

I need a cheap diy stable circuit for making an Adjustable PSU using LM317 Voltage Regulator. I got a adapter with output power supply of DC 30v 400mA. I need a circuit can  do both  variable voltage and variable amps. Lets say the voltage between (1-30 volts) and Amps between (10 mA-5 A)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: You can find sample applications in the datasheet for the LM317. Having said that, you are not going to have much success using this part for a 5A supply if your input is limited to 400mA. If you need a full CC/CV design, then the LM317 is not the ideal starting place. You can also find plenty of questions on this site about the topic. You will not get an output voltage of 30V from the LM317 if the input voltage is 30V. If you want 1V from 30V input at 5A from a linear regulator then you are going to be dissipating nearly 150W. Ouch!!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please take a look in this link [http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/5A-constant-current-constant-voltage-regualtor.png].. In the link its given that we can get a constant 5A output.

Comment: Sorry the link is https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuRJKesjXndHYbygecjIsSMcvg-is1DbCwSuefr3jhLkrNcqpoCqxeNER1Zg

Comment: That is not the point. You can certainly can get more than 1.5A in an LM317 design if you use a beefier pass element but your input power supply, in your photo, is limited to 400mA. It is a 12W supply, and you are asking for a 150W supply.

Comment: 30v 400mA = 12w. So can i get a output of 12v1amp constant op. ?! Is it possible

Comment: You cannot get 12V 1A from the 30V 400mA supply. That implies lossless conversion.

Comment: Thanks friend. Any suggestion for circuit design ?!

Comment: Circuit design begins with a specification, and you keep shifting the goalposts. You want to use the HP supply and an LM317, so you are constrained to at most about 28V at a maximum of 400mA.  Pick a specification.  You can have 'cheap diy' CC/CV, but 'stable' (how stable)? That is another matter. The main difficulty in designing a general purpose power supply is stabilizing it for all likely loads.

Comment: The LM317 is now considered harmful. It was a great product in its day, but times have changed. It is still good to read all the old app-notes because newer regulators work in much the same way. They just have improved specifications.